# can't disable debug level in logback.xml in java

Tags: java, logback

I have a lot of redundant information in console:
[pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/atBV2.png)

I have tried a lot of logback configuration

```
`   <logger name="org.apache.http.wire" level="OFF"/>
    <root level="error">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
        <appender-ref ref="FILE-THREAD"/>
    </root>

    <logger name="org.apache" level="ERROR" />
    <logger name="httpclient" level="ERROR" />
</configuration>`
```

It doesn't help.
In start log all looks ok:
[pic2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVH1v.png)

Dependensies:
logback-core RELEASE
logback-classic RELEASE

Could anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to delete libs in m2 repo, if you disable dependencies in pom!!!
 I had redundant log4j dependency in my project.